# In Python, what is a preferred naming convention for the backing store of an internal property?

Tags: python, properties

Say you have a public method in Python whose primary purpose is to retrieve the value of an underlying data attribute (i.e. internal backing store). The method may have lazy evaluation logic, etc. A property is an example of such a method.

Then it is natural to use the same name for the method and data attribute, except for an underscore prefix for the data attribute. For example--

```
class C(object):
def __init__(self):
    self._x = None

@property
def x(self):
    """I'm the 'x' property."""
    return self._x
```

(from [Python's "property" documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property))

But what are some preferred conventions if the method is for internal use and so is itself prefixed with an underscore?  Prefixing the backing store with two leading underscores would invoke name mangling and so is not ideal.

Two possibilities might be--

```
def _get_x(self):
    return self._x

def _x(self):
    return self._x_
```

Python style says the second (appending an underscore), though, should only be used to avoid conflicts with reserved keywords.

Comment: I am glad that comments cannot have a -1 score.

Comment: I think having a private property will confuse a lot of people.  I would suggest deriving your own class from `property` called, perhaps, `cached_property`, and defining `__get__` for it to call the getter if it hasn't been already, and if it has, return the value it returned when it was called.  And define `__delete__` to forget the cached value.

Comment: I just wrote one of those for myself, to see if it could be done.  And indeed it can, but it's a little ugly, and requires using weak references, which means that the class the property is put in has to be weak reference-able.

Answer (score 6):

The preferred convention is to use a single leading underscore.

This is the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendation for private attributes.

See this example in the docstring for property():

```
>>> help(property)
Help on class property in module builtins:

class property(object)
 |  property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None) -> property attribute
 |  
 |  fget is a function to be used for getting an attribute value, and likewise
 |  fset is a function for setting, and fdel a function for del'ing, an
 |  attribute.  Typical use is to define a managed attribute x:
 |  class C(object):
 |      def getx(self): return self._x
 |      def setx(self, value): self._x = value
 |      def delx(self): del self._x
 |      x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
 |  
 |  Decorators make defining new properties or modifying existing ones easy:
 |  class C(object):
 |      @property
 |      def x(self): return self._x
 |      @x.setter
 |      def x(self, value): self._x = value
 |      @x.deleter
 |      def x(self): del self._x
 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make it a property if it is for internal use? If it's for internal use, just access the attribute directly.

But then you would still use one underscore, but call it something else. But again, the whole point of making it a property is lost in this case.

Comment: You would want to make it a property if it needs to execute logic, for example lazy evaluation.

Comment: And then you can call that method directly, when it's internal.

Comment: -1 because this isn't an answer, though I misread the question initially and so gave you the wrong answer to your question.  @Chris J has a good answer.

Comment: Don't mess with Lennart folks.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan, ahh, so this is a club now that has preferred members?  Pity I wasn't informed.  Any other untouchables I should know about?

Comment: Omnifarious, I will give you an answer if you can tell me what my name means.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan, I believe it means 'rowdy scottsman' or 'red-neck scottsman'.